# setInterval not working with document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm completely confused as I'm not a Javascript beginner...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var loadtime = 2000;
  var loadtimer = setInterval(function(){
    loadtime = loadtime - 100;
    console.log(loadtime);
  }, 100);
});
```

This is not working for me. The console output is:
`1900`

I want the script to output every 100 milliseconds the current `loadtime`.

Where is my fault?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't print 1800 ... 1700 etc? I would expect that it does. How do you think `document.ready` is related?

Comment: [Not reproducable](http://jsfiddle.net/grmdvzm2/)?

Comment: I don't understand. `loadtime` is 2k and you subtract 100, so the first time it has to be 1900. What's wrong exactly?

Comment: If you want it to start with printing 2000 put your console.log statement before the subtraction.

Comment: I want it to output 1900, 1800, 1700, ...

Comment: https://www.sese7.de/js/main.js

Comment: You're clearing the timer when the promise is fullfilled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work - [check this demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kb671v5j/).

```
  var loadtime = 2000;
  var loadtimer = setInterval(function(){
    loadtime = loadtime - 100;
    console.log(loadtime);
  }, 100);
```

## edit

The reason it doesn't work is that you call:

```
clearInterval(loadtimer);
```

Which stops your `setInterval` function about after first run.

Comment: Then you have to tell us what is the difference between your JS compiler and the one we have in browsers.